# how to reference for jquery in a c# webview when html is generated by string

Tags: c#, jquery, webview, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I need to reference jquery file that is in my resources folder "/Resources/jquery.js". When I load it into the webview the html will appear but the jquery doesn't work. I'm using visual studio 2013 and want this to work on windows phone 8.1, Here is what I try to do.

```
private void mWebview_Loaded(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e){
String html="<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n    <script src=\"/Resources/jquery.js\">\r\n    </script>\r\n    <script>\r\n    $(document).ready(function(){\r\n        $(\"p\").click(function(){\r\n        $(this).hide();\r\n        });\r\n    });\r\n    </script>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n    <button onclick=\"show()\">Press!</button>\r\n    <p id=\"p\">Dummy</p>\r\n    <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>\r\n    <p>Click me away!</p>\r\n    <p>Click me too!</p>\r\n\r\n</body>\r\n</html>"
mWebView.NavigateToString(html);
}
```

If the string is too complicated to read it a copy of http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide but I have replaced the source attribute of the script to where my jquery file is.

Is there a specific way this needs to be done when using webview in phones apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to fix this is in the source you need to use the prefix ms-appx-web:// so the source would now look like this.
     src="ms-appx-web:///Resources/jquery.js"

This is also usefell for referencing local css files.

I hope this helps people in the future

Answer (score 0):

If you *Resources* folder is in the same directory than the file you are working on, you must remove the `/`. The path you wrote, in HTML means `../Resources/jquery.js`

Anyway, placing the whole html in a variable is so ugly, you can create a Page.html into your project, then

```
WebView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Page.html", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: The reason I'm using in as NavigateToString is because in the future I want to programatically change what is going into the webview. Are you saying the new line would be ' src="Resources/jquery.js" '. I can't test this now but thanks for your help @the_nuts

Comment: This didn't work although I have found the soloution.